# How to select different count data in one row in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select certain data from a table on sql server which has a following structure :

```
TABLE A
    |TYPE_ID| |CT| |DUE_DATE|
```

Now the output that I need is :

```
|TYPE_ID| |COUNT_TODAY| |COUNT_ONE_WEEK| |COUNT_ONE_MONTH|
```

How can I select all the counts in one row?

I can do that in multiple rows because there I can have different rows on each having it's own where clause comparing dates.

```
|TYPE_ID| |COUNT| |IS_TODAY| |IS_ONE_MONTH|
```

I can get this by following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(CT),1,0 FROM A WHERE DUE_DATE = GETDATE() 
SELECT COUNT(CT),0,1 FROM A WHERE DUE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())
```

However I need the Output as describe above/

Comment: Btw, the transformation you are looking for is called pivoting and has been asked and answered here on SO several times.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow, well I never knew the term otherwise I would have searched the concept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select typeid,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end) as today,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= cast(getdate() - 7 as date) then 1 else 0 end) as week,
       sum(case when cast(due_date as date) >= dateadd(month, -1, cast(getdate() as date)) then 1 else 0 end) as month
from t
group by typeid;
```